# How to display html text inside UILabel according to html tags?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

```
   NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[stringFromHtml dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil]
   self.textLabel.attributedText = attrString;
   self.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0];
```

This code ignores `<b> </b>` and `<i> </i>` tags, but reacts on another tags (\t \r \n 
)

**EDITED:**

This code works for me ONLY then i comment 2nd line (`NSFontAttributeName`) - in that case font is default and tags like `<b>, <i>` are NOT ignored.
But if i want my font style - tags ignored again...... wtf? :)

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrHTMLText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[eventText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
    [attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
    self.textLabel.attributedText = attrHTMLText;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSAttributedString` with option like `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` as `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`

```
//create NSMutableAttributedString for adding attributes as per required
NSMutableAttributedString *attrHTMLText = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[yourHTMTextHere dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
//set font here
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:yourLabel.font range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
//set color here
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];

//Now set attribute text to your Label
yourLabel.attributedText = attrHTMLText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally i will use following link for html text in UILabel, it works for me. just drag and drop it's class file and see what things it can do.

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel

Hope this link will help you.